# Quantum gates execution times on IBM Q Melbourne

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience

I am interested in the execution time of quantum gates on IBM's $15$-qubits Melbourne computer. Is there any information regarding this?

After searching for a while I have only managed to find the times of the `CNOT` gates [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/ibmq-device-information/blob/master/backends/melbourne/V1/version_log.md), but unfortunately, no information for other quantum operations. I am specifically interested in the Hadamard gate `.h()` and the phase and rotation gates `.rz()` and `.u3()`, as well as the simple inverter `.x()`. I know these gates are not elementary (i.e they are composite gates) but still, any information regarding their respective execution times would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the information about execution times on a backend by using the `.properties()` method in Qiskit. In your example, this can be done as follows

```
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
backend.properties()
```

This returns an object containing all the gate times.

It is worth noting that all single qubit gates get converted into `u3` gates, and all multiqubit gates converted to use `cx`, so that they can be run on the real hardware. If you want to see how a specific circuit is converted into this format you can use the transpiler, for example `new_qc = transpile(qc, optimization_level=3)`